# keep values of seleted multiple and use them to create table jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, select

I want to know how to keep the different values ​​of a multiple selection and then create an array from jQuery.

Let me explain,

my multiple selection I have 5 values:

```
<select name="animal" id="animal" multiple="multiple"> 
    
<option> value="30"> Cat </ option> 
<option> value="31"> Dog </ option> 
<option> value="32"> Bird </ option> 
<option> value="33"> Cow </ option> 
<option> value="34"> Fox </ option> 

</ select>
```

I choose for example values: 30, 32, 34

and when I click on my "show" button, I want it to create a table that looks like this:

```
  <table> 
       <thead> 
          <tr> 
            <th> 
              Animal 
            </ th> 
            <th> 
              Cat 
            </ th> 
            <th> 
              Bird 
            </ th> 
            <th> 
              Fox 
            </ th> 
         </ tr> 
       </ thead> 
       <tbody> 
       </ tbody> 
    </ table>
```

How to make this with jQuery please ?

I hope I have explained my problem.

Thank you for your future answers.

Comment: @Kiranramchandran Don't edit away errors in the code, or the original poster won't know that he did something wrong, and the existing answers referring to those errors won't make sense anymore.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First make the markup for the `select` valid.  The `option` tags were being closed too early, causing the attributes not to be part of the tag.

```
<select name="animal" id="animal" multiple="multiple"> 
<option value="30"> Cat </option> 
<option value="31"> Dog </option> 
<option value="32"> Bird </option> 
<option value="33"> Cow </option> 
<option value="34"> Fox </option> 
</select>
```

Also add the button and table to your markup:

```
<button>Show Table</button>
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Then use the following Javascript/jQuery:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    var html;
    $("#animal option:selected").each(function(){
        html += "<th>" + this.text + "</th>";
    });
    $("table thead tr").append(html);
});
```

**JS Fiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/233b3/

If you must generate the entire table dynamically, here is another [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/233b3/1/).